# HTML5 meter in mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, mobile-safari, modernizr

I'm in the process of developing a mobile web app that needs a meter and preferably an HTML5 meter. Currently Mobile Safari does NOT support the meter element but I was hoping to use Modernizr and a Polyfill to get it to work, but i've had no luck so far.

Any suggestion on how to get the meter working? OR any good alternatives to HTML5 meter?

Here the current page, it's pretty straight forward:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>untitled</title>

<script src="modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.meterShim.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.meterShim.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<header>
</header>

 <meter value="4" min="0" max="10">4/10</meter>

    <footer>
</footer>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was able to find another polyfill that actually worked. For anyone who needs to do this in the future please try this polyfill: https://gist.github.com/667320

Answer (score -1):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_meter.asp) meter tag will support only in opera and chrome, as an alternative you can use [jquery progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/)

Comment: Thats is true but using Polyfills you are able to get it functioning. I was able to find another polyfill that actually functions.